# How to Estimate Deployment of a Contract on Mainnet Using Foundry

Tags: contract-deployment, testing, foundry

I'm trying to estimate the deployment cost of a smart contract on the Ethereum Mainnet using Foundry. Can anyone provide guidance or a step-by-step process for making this estimation accurately?